# Header flip/RMB

Tags: customization, theme

Is there a way to set the headers so they are always at the top, as default?

I can set them manually one at a time with a RMB, but this is distracting because you set it one way in one window, it does not do the same for all future windows, for example node editor, 3Dview.

Comment: Once you get a setup you prefer,  you can create a startup template file with the menu File >> Defaults >> Save Startup File, and then click *Save...* that pops up to verify.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know could be to set all of them manually in a file, and then set that file as default startup file, from the blender "file" menu (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd>)

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I am doing now.  If I add a new pane, got the same problem.  Another possibility is to create Python code, and tie to a hotkey; at least I minimize mouse movements.  As a newbie, mastering and memorizing the GUI is critical.  The header placement is a major distraction on concentration, particularly the pull down menus and the flip of the order of items.  Surprised this is not in preferences.